# Prove that $y'$ is a function of $y$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, functions, chain-rule, reduction-of-order-ode

First, some context:

This occurred to me while I was learning how to do order reduction for $2^{nd}$ order ODEs of the form $F(y, y', y'') = 0$.

Apparently, I'm supposed to set $p = y'$, say that $y'' = p_x = p_y * y' = p_y * p$ (according to the chain rule), and then solve $F(y, p, p_y * p) = 0$, which is now a $1^{st}$ order ODE.

However, I have to ask: What *is* $p$? My first instinct would be to say that it is a function of $x$. But here it is being treated as a function of $y$ (unless there is some variation to the chain rule I'm unaware of).

So this leads me to believe that $p$, and by extension $y'$, are functions of $y$.
But why? We can't necessarily solve the original equation to prove that it is the case - so how can we prove it?

Comment: If $p(x) := \frac{d}{dx} y(x)$, then $\frac{d}{dx} p(x) = \frac{d^2}{dx^2} y(x)$.

There is no chain rule in this setting! (Since $x$ is the only variable we differentiate...)

Comment: @SteffenPlunder Yes for the $y'' = p_x$ part of the equality, but what about the rest? Besides, doesn't the order reduction itself need p to be a function of y?

Comment: This page contains an explanation of the method used: http://www.copingwithcalculus.com/reduction-of-order.html

Answer (score 0):

Unless $y$ is a constant, $y'=p$ is a function of $x$. Consequently, there is a functional relation between $p$ and $y$ (via $y=f(x)\leftrightarrow x=f^{-1}(y)$).

E.g. $y=e^x\to p=e^x=y$.

Comment: I can understand that, but to do the order reduction, don't you need p to be a function of y? Otherwise you end up with $F(y(x), p(x), p_y(x) * p(x)) = 0$ Which isn't much help

Comment: Maybe my answer was too long. Short form: "There is a functional relation between $p$ and $y$".

Comment: But how do we know f is invertible in the first place?

Comment: @gtsiam: I don't mean that it is invertible. You can decompose in branches.

Comment: Could you give an example for, say, $y=x^2$? what would be $f^-1$?

Comment: @gtsiam: you don't seem to be willing that a functional relation exists, I can't help you further.

Comment: You're right, now that Im reading the answer better, I see what you mean; I originally thought you were talking about the general case. I'm sorry, English is my second language. But still, why does that relation exist? Can it be proven through knowing that $F(y, y', y'')=0$, or is it an unsaid requirement to perform the above technique?

Comment: @gtsiam : You consider segments of some thought-as-fixed solution where $y(x)$ is a monotonous function. Then by elementary calculus $x$ and $y'(x)$ can be expressed as function of $y$. This of course means that in the end you also have to discuss how the so analyzed pieces of the solution fit together.

Answer (score 0):

I'm just trying to explain it from a physical perspective. Maybe that helps you.

In short: Is $p$ *in general* a function of $y$?

No!

$p$ is computed as the derivative of $y(x)$. Hence, if we only know a value $y_1 \in \mathbb{R}$, then we cannot compute $p_1$ as a function of $y_1$.
There are ways to recover $p$ in special cases. But I guess that these cases are not important for you at the moment.

Long answer:

**Case 1: We known $y(x)$ explicitly.**

Let us assume first, that we know $y(x)$ already, we interpret $x$ as time and $y(x)$ as the position at time $x$.

To make it explicit, we take: $y(x) := x^3$.

Now, we can compute the velocity of the trajectory as $y'(x) = 3x^2$.
When we define $p = y'$ is means that $p$ is the velocity of the trajectory.

*Question:* If you know the position of an object, do you automatically know it's velocity?

Since we know $y(x) = x^3$ we can compute for a given position $y_1$ the corresponding time $x_1$. Namely, $x_1 = \sqrt[3]{y_1}$.

In this case there is a global one-to-one relation between the current velocity $p_1 = p(x_1)$ and the position$y_1 = y(x_1)$:
$$
p_1 = 3 x_1^2 = 3 ( \sqrt[3]{y_1})^2.
$$

But this is not always the case, for example if $y(x) := x^2$, then no such relation exists.

For a given position $y_1 := y(x_1)$ the corresponding time could be $\pm \sqrt{y_1}$.
Hence, knowing the position $y_1$ at one time-point is not sufficient anymore to find the velocity $p_1$!

Remark: If we know the positions for a whole time-interval, i.e.
$y(x)$ for $x \in [x_1,x_2]$, then we have enough data to determine the velocity uniquely.
But this is not very useful for us.

**Case 2: $y(x)$ is a solution of $F(y,y',y'',x)$**

A trajectory $y(x)$ which solves the equation $F(y(x),y'(x),y''(x),x) = 0$ (for all $x$) is often a very special function.
However, it depends on $F$ if we can determine $y(x)$ uniquely from that equation!

For example if we define $F(y,y',y'',x) := 0$ than any trajectory $y(x)$ solves $F = 0$. Hence, in this case there are no condition on the trajectory at all.

**Therefore, an underlying condition for implicit differential equations is
that we can solve $F(y,y',y'',x) = 0$ with respect to $y''$.**

In physical terms: If we know the time $x$, the position $y$ and the velocity $y'$, then we can determine the acceleration $y''$ (typically via Newton's law).

However, if we can determine the velocity already from the positions, i.e.
if for a fixed values $y_1, x_1 \in \mathbb R$ there is some acceleration $a_1$ and **a unique value** $p_1 \in \mathbb R$ such that $F(y_1,p_1,a_1,x_1) = 0$, then the ODE is in fact a first-order ODE.
So, if a functional relation $p(y)$ follows directly by algebraic manipulation of $F = 0$, then the system is a first-order ODE, namely $y' = p(y)$.

Let me shortly come back to the example 1 form the link you sent in the comments:
$$F(y,y',y'',x) = x y'' - y'.$$

We see, that we can solve $F = 0$ for $y''$, i.e.
$$y'' = \frac{y'}{x}.$$
(i.e. we satisfy the invertibility assumption on $F$.)

If we introduce $p(x) = y'(x)$ this equation becomes $p'(x) = \frac{p(x)}{x}$.
The reason why the example ask you to consider $x p'(x) = p$ is only to make the computations easier. But this is not the chain rule!

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to write this, but I'm having some trouble wrapping my head around it. Looking at example 3, from the link, you can't solve for $y'$ uniquely by algebraic manipulation. Also in the answer, you're solving for $y'$ then for $y''$ then back, which makes it a bit confusing. Finally, regarding the examples, I was talking about the case where $F(y, y', y'') = 0$ (no x), so that would mean Examples 3 and 4.